# Django - [Errno 13] Permission denied - Win10

Tags: python, django, pip, windows-10, errno

I am currently trying to install and set-up Django.

I am using windows 10 and python 3.9.

When i run
`pip install django` I get the following error: `ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno13] Permission denied: 'c:\\python39\\Scripts\\django-admin.py'`.

From reading other questions, adding `--user` to the command works.  However, the command `django-admin` is still not recognised.

Any ideas on how to fix the error?

Comment: I think you need to install `django-admin` separately. It's a standalone module.

Comment: @pavel I tried `pip install django-admin`.  This seems to have installed correctly, however `django-admin` is still not recognised unfortunately.